# How can i debug an error while trying to add migration?

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-core-3.1

Is there any way of displaying more useful information instead of getting the following?

I currently use `add-migration test1 -context mycontext`

Update: added the `-verbose` option with no real new valuable information

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'key')
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityReferenceMap.TryGet(Object entity, IEntityType entityType, InternalEntityEntry& entry, Boolean throwOnNonUniqueness)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.TryGetEntry(Object entity, IEntityType entityType, Boolean throwOnTypeMismatch)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NavigationFixer.KeyPropertyChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, IProperty property, IReadOnlyList`1 containingPrincipalKeys, IReadOnlyList`1 containingForeignKeys, Object oldValue, Object newValue)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntryNotifier.KeyPropertyChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, IProperty property, IReadOnlyList`1 keys, IReadOnlyList`1 foreignKeys, Object oldValue, Object newValue)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.ChangeDetector.DetectKeyChange(InternalEntityEntry entry, IProperty property)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.ChangeDetector.PropertyChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, IPropertyBase propertyBase, Boolean setModified)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntryNotifier.PropertyChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, IPropertyBase property, Boolean setModified)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetProperty(IPropertyBase propertyBase, Object value, Boolean isMaterialization, Boolean setModified, Boolean isCascadeDelete, CurrentValueType valueType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetProperty(IPropertyBase propertyBase, Object value, Boolean isMaterialization, Boolean setModified, Boolean isCascadeDelete)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.CascadeDelete(InternalEntityEntry entry, Boolean force, IEnumerable`1 foreignKeys)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.UpdateAdapter.CascadeDelete(IUpdateEntry entry, IEnumerable`1 foreignKeys)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.GetDataOperations(DiffContext diffContext)+MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ConcatIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Sort(IEnumerable`1 operations, DiffContext diffContext)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.GetDifferences(IModel source, IModel target)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.MigrationsScaffolder.ScaffoldMigration(String migrationName, String rootNamespace, String subNamespace, String language)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'key')
```

Comment: Does your dotnet build run succesfully?